# Поиск по тексту, игнорируя регистр

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Имеется текст с однотипными данными, но написанные вручную не по шаблону, а "от балды", например:

1 страница:

```
ИНН: 112233
КПП: 445566
Наименование получателя: Рога и Копыта
...
```

2 страница:

```
инн: 112233
Кпп: 445566
получатель: Рога и Копыта
...
```

Поиск, предположим, по 3 (получатель) полю.
Дабы не задавать условие:

```
if(line.contains("получател") || line.contains("Получател") || line.contains("ПОЛУЧАТЕЛ") || ...)
```

Можно ли вести поиск более лаконично, игнорируя регистр?

Comment: `line.toUpperCase().contains("ПОЛУЧАТЕЛ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(line.toLowerCase().contains("получател"))
```